# How to create a Views based chart with time intervals and using Highcharts?

Tags: views, charts

Is there any change to do time interval to Highcharts -module ?

Such as in this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Or do I need to use different module for that?

Comment: if you need the from & to date filter that you see in the top right corner of the demo chart - then all you need is exposed date filter in your View.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Now it works fine with highcharts :)

Answer (score 0):

The [example in your question](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) looks like a variation of this chart:

[image]

The above is a screenprint of a chart created with the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, for which [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is one of the supported charting engines (apart from [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)). So consider this module as a possible alternative to create such chart(s).

Head over to the Community documentation [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837) for details about how to use the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

**Disclosure**: I'm a co-maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).